# problem with .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I am getting the following error after uploading files in server:

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

For development purposes, I am using the following server URL: http://dev.example.mhd.co.us.

I am not able to access site when it has its .htaccess file; when I remove the .htacess file, it works fine. I am using the default file that comes with Drupal. I need to enable the clean URLs on the site.; mod_rewrite is enabled.

Is there anything else I need to configure?
Do you have any idea about why I have problems?

Comment: Can you please share your `.htaccess` here ?

Answer (score 3):

That usually means *something* in your .htaccess is causing Apache to fail. Could for example be a missing module or a configuration that denies access to something.

Try to look at the error log of the Apache server, if you have access to it. If not (even many shared hosting sites allow access to those files for your virtual host), you could ask your hosting provider support.

It is only possible to provide a more detailed solution once you post the actual error from the error log.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Is any-other way to read apache configurations which are enabled in server through php code,like phpinfo().

Comment: No, I don't think so. Again, check your logs. Everything else is just blindly guessing. Once you can provide the actual error message from the log, this should be much easier to resolve.

Answer (score 2):

This error is due to .htaccess syntax error. Restore your .htaccess

For enabling Clean URLs you must have `mod_rewrite` enabled.

Make sure if `RewriteEngine On` in .htaccess

Setting .htaccess for Drupal that is extracted on the www-root. (e.g. example.com/)
Uncomment the following line from .htaccess:

`RewriteBase /`

If Drupal is extracted in sub directory (e.g. example.com/subdir/)

`RewriteBase /subdir/`

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.It didn't work's for me.If i place a single code throwing internal error.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run Drupal on this host before (or even Wordpress)?  I have run into hosting companies that disable a lot of the directives in the standard Drupal `.htaccess` file, and this can cause Apache to throw 500 errors.